# How to calculate significance between more than two levels of a mean cumulative function estimate in R's REDA package?

Tags: r, p-value, nonparametric, mean-cumulative-function

Concerning the R's REDA package:
HTML Tutorial: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reda/vignettes/reda-intro.html
CRAN's package API documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reda/reda.pdf

**How do I calculate a significance test on a one MCF object with categorical variable of three or more levels?**

Using the package data as an example, we can calculate for **two levels**:

```
library(reda)
str(simuDat)
```

Notice that "group" has two levels: *Treat* and *Contr*. Now perform an MCF estimate with default values:

```
simuMcf <- mcf(Recur(time, ID, event) ~ group, data = simuDate)
```

Comparing the two-sample MCFs between the treatment and control group in the simulated data:

```
mcf_diff0 <- mcfDiff(simuMcf)
```

Results in:

```
## 
## Two-Sample Pseudo-Score Tests:
##                 Statistic Variance    Chisq DF Pr(>Chisq)   
## Constant Weight   52.5855 670.1014   4.1266  1   0.042214 * 
## Linear Weight     35.7687 158.9869   8.0472  1   0.004557 **
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Variance Estimator: robust
```

**However, how do I perform a statistical test if my categorical variable has three or more levels?** For example:

```
drugRes <- <- mcf(Recur(time, ID, event) ~ drugName, data = drugDF)
```

where: str(drugDF) yields something similar to:

```
## 'data.frame':    500 obs. of  6 variables:
##  $ ID    : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4 ...
##  $ time  : num  1 22 23 57 112 140 40 168 14 112 ...
##  $ event : int  1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
##  $ drugName : Factor w/ 3 levels "DMSO","Amitriptyline","Topiramate": 1 1 1 3 1 2 1 1 3 1 ...
##  $ x1    : num  -1.93 -1.93 -1.93 -1.93 -1.93 -0.11 0.2 0.2 -0.43 -0.43 ...
##  $ gender: Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

In the HTML tutorial, you might read the code comment: "## one sample MCF object of two groups" followed by the example for "## explicitly ask for the difference of two sample MCF". Please note, I am using one sample MCF object with more than two groups (the names of drugs in my case).

Comment: You seem to have introduced two new tags here [tag:mcf] and [tag:mean-cumulative-function]. Why two? Can you write tag wikis?

Comment: Please provide further information, your comment is somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: Go to [this tag page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mean-cumulative-function), see the first line .... tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it? ... click on that, and write a short "excerpt" explanation of the use of your new tag!

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I certainly can.